# User already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Tags: mysql-connect

I have one shared hosting account and i am running dynamic site there. i am facing below problem sometime where database record returns.

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: User myuser already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in path/db.php on line 4
Could not connect: User myuser already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

I am closing all connections like mysql_close($con) in each file where i execute the query;

is it just because of this ? or there could be some other issue?
can i trace out the problem where i am missing the mysql closing connection ?

can someone help me out ? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079531/mysqli-error-user-already-has-more-than-max-user-connections-active-connectio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not open and close connection on each file or worse on each query. Make a file similar to `connection.php` where you put the mysql_connect statement and use `require_once` where you want to use it.
do not use `mysql_close` since the connection gets closed automatically each time the script finishes.

Comment: This is not a programming problem, just quantity of resources available. And any other script that uses this class are subject to have the error.