# Laravel - User 'root' already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have recently started using Laravel and absolutely love it, however I keep coming across the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User 'root' already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

I know there is a way to change the MySQL variable to allow more connections, however this isn't an option with my host and along with this, there is no way I should of hit this limit.

Some example queries are:

```
return User::where('users.username', '=', Auth::user()->username)->join('settings', 'settings.username', '=', 'users.username')->first();
return Char::orderBy('calculate', 'ASC')->groupBy('charid')->get();
```

So my question is, what should I be looking for in order to combat the error? Should I be disconnecting myself from the database at the end of each function? Or something completely different?

Any help would be appreciated in this matter.

Comment: You have to show your queries too for Eloquent or Query Builder.

Comment: Updated main post to reflect this

Comment: You might want to update your Laravel install. Laravel should be properly handling this for you.

Comment: I've just updated to 4.1, however the issue was still present in 4.0

Comment: Did you change anything? Must be your hosts problem.

Comment: No, this error has only started occurring since an increase in the user base

Comment: Same problem, born with increasing user base, tried PDO persistent connection not solving..

Answer (score 0):

No, Once Change the username **root** to following username like **system a**nd try it

Comment: I've just change it to root for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 0):

What version of Laravel do you have?
Go to "application/config.database.php" or "app/config/database.php". From here you can add custom options to your laravel database settings.

The "database.php" contains at the end something like this:

```
    'connections' => array(


    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'db_name',
        'username' => 'db_username',
        'password' => 'username_password',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

),
```

You can add "options" to that array, just like this:

```
    'connections' => array(


    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'db_name',
        'username' => 'db_username',
        'password' => 'username_password',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'options'  => array(
                            //here you will add your custom options
                      ),
    ),

),
```

Comment: I've added the following:

    'options'   => array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 20,
            ),

but still have the issue

Comment: try: 'options'   => array(
    PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 0,
   ),  for unlimited time. If it still don't work, the problem is your computer/host, in this case you'll find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4079589/1564840