# CodeIgniter too many connections

Tags: php, codeigniter

Suddenly my project starts saying there's too many connections to the database.

> "my_mysql_user already has more than 'max_user_connections' active
>   connections"

This always worked fine and I'm using multidatabase and the settings are

```
$config['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['username'] = 'my_mysql_user';
$config['password'] = 'my_mysql_password';
$config['database'] = ($db == null ? $this->CI->session->company['db'] : $db);
$config['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$config['dbprefix'] = '';
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$config['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$config['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

And I need to load like 20/30 models..and I always load them in the `__construct()` of the controller.

Even thought it always worked, I thought I might change it and load the models only in the functions that are needed, and the problem persists.

By executing `SHOW PROCESSLIST` it returns nothing, there's no query being done.

What can I do to track the problem? It seems the connections are not closed!

Comment: see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47131/how-to-get-rid-of-maximum-user-connections-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079531/mysqli-error-user-already-has-more-than-max-user-connections-active-connectio hope these links help to figure it out

Comment: Here's the only thing that worked in our case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226015/error-too-many-connections-on-codeigniter-website

Answer (score 0):

Turn off persistent connections.

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

If you want to prevent them from MySQL, set in my.cnf:

```
mysql.allow_persistent=Off
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I sent a ticket to my hosting asking for that. I'll see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @Linesofcode this normally may not be set for a shared server. you would need a VPS or dedicated server for global mysql server changes to be made

Comment: @Vickel I printed the phpinfo() and it is indeed the variable set to true `mysqli.allow_persistent=on` and I asked them to change it. What it bothers me is the fact it was suddenly that this start becoming a problem..and why?

Comment: @Linesofcode maybe they upgraded mysql/apache/php version, they do that all the time and normally never advise (shared server)

Comment: What has changed recently? Something has. You must consider the entire infrastructure involved with this from end-to-end. What has changed?

Comment: Additionally, the `my.cnf` change is not necessary if you turn off persistent connection in CI. That is only a nice to have anyway.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I didn't change a thing in the last month !! The only reason I can see it's my hosting fault !!

Comment: @RandyCasburn and btw, it works perfectly on my local environment !!

Comment: @Linesofcode check also your localhost environment (mysql, php, CI version) versus your production environment, if you see them upgrading, you at least can track it

Comment: @Vickel everything is OK in terms of versions, both CI and PHP versions match, besides I have like 30 different pages and everything works fine, only one has problem. The `Show processlist` does not return any query being done..fml !!

Comment: It sure does sound like you've isolated it to your ISP. if all versions are same, absolutely nothing has changed that you know of, all versions of all software(s) match, and it works locally but not in deployed environment, the only thing that could have changed, given all these assertions, is at your ISP. Good luck.

Comment: @RandyCasburn well, my hosting rebooted the MySQL, increased the user limitation and everything started working. I need to understand what lead to the error, but its complicated. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah - looks like maybe you've been lucky up until now. Some investigation is necessary. If you enjoyed my help, please accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: tried it but not sure if it works , i will monitor first