# How to fix message: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1203 error

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My website runs fine on localhost but when deploying it to shared hosting. I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1203
>   User id11846490_otisljoe already has more than 'max_user_connections'
>   active connections (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `invoices`
>   where `title` = Invoice and `invoices`.`deleted_at` is null)

I figured out and, googled why it occurred but I can found the solution.

Comment: Shared host give very limited resource, you should deploy to vps hosting or better shared hosting which give more `max_user_connections`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079531/mysqli-error-user-already-has-more-than-max-user-connections-active-connectio